# DITA-OT PDF formatter xsl:attribute-set names documentation

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, dita, dita-ot

I've recently started generating and styling my DITA documents with [DITA-OT](https://www.dita-ot.org) and Apache FOP 2.4 PDF formatter. My problem is that I haven't found a comprehensive documentation about the `xsl:attribute-set` elements which essentially style the resulting PDFs.

With the help of the [official DITA-OT PDF XSL documents](https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/tree/develop/src/main/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/cfg/fo/attrs) and the plugin generated by [jelovirt's PDF generator](http://dita-generator.elovirta.com) I can experiment a bit and change some values which define the basic properties of a page, however I find this "reverse documentation" learning inefficient.

My question is, do you know about any documentation which lists the names of the different generated elements of org.dita.pdf2 to be able to style them?

Like the titles can be formatted with `topic.title` attribute set, text bodies with `common.block`, etc.

In its simplest form something like a graphics depicting an A4 paper saying the header can be styled with this attribute-set, the footer with something else, those are the different text blocks, etc.

I'm fairly new in the DITA world, so there might be an obvious place to look at, but unfortunately, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to purchase "DITA for Print (2nd Edition)" by Leigh White. In addition, you'll probably find the dita-users list at Groups.io to be the most useful resource for questions about DITA and PDF.

Answer (score 0):

After some ineffective search I've written a simple Perl script which searches through all the `xsl:attribute-set` properties of org.dita.pdf2 plugin. It outputs its results Markup-formatted which, together with the script, I uploaded to a git repository.

You can find them here: [DITA Open Toolkit org.dita.pdf2 attribute set documentation](https://github.com/szotsaki/dita-ot-pdf-attribute-set-documentation).